# XML Skip 'wrong' event type

Tags: php, xml

I have a certain BLOATED XML file that i use to generate a Gallery with some few information about the Picture. Besides of the Actual needed NEW there are plenty of entries with OLD, adding more pictures, but creating also duplicate entries.

```
<result>
<event>
  <date>2015-04-14T22:19:02+02:00</date>
  <type>OLD</type>
  <value1>AAA</value1>
  <id>changingIDwhatever</id>
  <profile>
    <url>/domainpart/SPECIFICNAME/?w=</url>
    <name>SPECIFICNAME</name>
    <value2>BBB</value2>
    <value3>CCC</value3>
    <value4>DDD</value4>
      <image>
        <url>http://domain.tld/path/to/the/image/320.jpg?1234-ab1cd2e345fg6789</url>
        <width>320</width>
      </image>
  </profile>
</event>
<event>
  <date>2015-04-14T22:19:02+02:00</date>
  <type>NEW</type>
  <value1>AAA</value1>
  <id>changingIDwhatever</id>
  <profile>
    <url>/domainpart/ANOTHERNAME/?w=</url>
    <name>ANOTHERNAME</name>
    <value2>BBB</value2>
    <value3>CCC</value3>
    <value4>DDD</value4>
      <image>
        <url>http://domain.tld/path/to/the/image/320.jpg?1234-ab1cd2e345fg6789</url>
        <width>320</width>
      </image>
  </profile>
</event>
<event>
  <date>2015-04-14T22:19:02+02:00</date>
  <type>NEW</type>
  <value1>AAA</value1>
  <id>changingIDwhatever</id>
  <profile>
    <url>/domainpart/SPECIFICNAME/?w=</url>
    <name>SPECIFICNAME</name>
    <value2>BBB</value2>
    <value3>CCC</value3>
    <value4>DDD</value4>
      <image>
        <url>http://domain.tld/path/to/the/image/320.jpg?1234-ab1cd2e345fg6789</url>
        <width>320</width>
      </image>
  </profile>
</event>
</result>
```

I do generate everything in a pretty neat layout in a very basic way. As i have really NO knowledge at all about php, i usually base on skriptpieces i find that are kind of put together in a way that the outcome mostly is the way i need it.

```
<?php
//###################Config Start#########################
$memberid = "123456";
$maxAnzahl = 50;
$zaehler = 0;
$baseURL = "http://www.domain.tld";
//###################Config End#########################
$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://key:keypass@www.domain.tld/news/xml');
$events = $feed->events;
foreach ($events->event as $event) {
echo "<div class='4u'>";
echo "<article class='box style2'>";
if ($event->type == "newMember") {
echo "<a href='".$baseURL.$event->profile->url.$memberid."' class='image featured' target='_blank'><img src='" . $event->profile->image->url . "' alt='' /> </a>";
} else {
echo "<a href='".$baseURL.$event->profile->url.$memberid."' class='image featured' target='_blank'><img src='" . $event->image->url . "' alt='' /> </a>";
}
echo "<h3><a href='".$baseURL.$event->profile->url.$memberid."'>" . $event->profile->name . "</a></h3>";
echo "</article>";
echo "</div>";
$zaehler = $zaehler + 1;
if ($zaehler == $maxAnzahl) {
break;
}
}
?>
```

Would be someone able to tell me how i could specify now in that skript how to SKIP all OLD ?

Kind Regards
Caylean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution myself *sigh* I was blind to it, till i got the first reply, checked my question AGAIN and saw a marker that I normally wanted to change everywhere to make it CLEAR what i needed.

In my initial question was a line "*if ($event->type == "newMember") {*" Normally i had to change it to "NEW" like in my example, to help ppl who wanted to help, to see it more easy.... Well, now i saw it and it made everything clear to me.

Changing the code like:

```
<?php
//###################Config Start#########################
$memberid = "123456";
$maxAnzahl = 50;
$zaehler = 0;
$baseURL = "http://www.domain.tld";
//###################Config End#########################
$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://key:keypass@www.domain.tld/news/xml');
$events = $feed->events;
foreach ($events->event as $event) {
if ($event->type == "NEW") {
echo "<div class='4u'>";
echo "<article class='box style2'>";
echo "<a href='".$baseURL.$event->profile->url.$memberid."' class='image featured' target='_blank'><img src='" . $event->profile->image->url . "' alt='' /> </a>";
echo "<h3><a href='".$baseURL.$event->profile->url.$memberid."'>" . $event->profile->name . "</a></h3>";
echo "</article>";
echo "</div>";
} else {
echo "";
}
$zaehler = $zaehler + 1;
if ($zaehler == $maxAnzahl) {
break;
}
}
?>
```

Gives me exactly the Images and Content i was looking for. For some reason i had already the solution in the code, but it was somehow messed up.

Thank you anyways for the help and thoughts!

Comment: Well, completely answered it is NOT, as i am unable to show the amount of Entries i want to have in that site!!! If the Amount of Entries to show is set very high, It shows me either everything it can find in the xml (XML shows max 30 results) OR (now comes an expection, as i have no idea if i am right) if i want to have 4 results, it CHECKS the first four results, finds maybe only 1 result and shows now only 1 Result. Properbly as i am missing some kind of else statement that tells the skript NOT to count for OLD

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of tasks like query the XML structure I prefer to use [XPATH.](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)

Try like this. I hope works for you.

```
<?php
    // Get the XML
    //###################Config Start#########################
    $memberid = "123456";
    $maxAnzahl = 50;
    $zaehler = 0;
    $baseURL = "http://www.domain.tld";
    //###################Config End#########################
    $source = file_get_contents('http://key:keypass@www.domain.tld/news/xml');

    // DOM document Creation
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->loadXML($source);

    // DOM XPath Creation
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    // Get all NEW events ONLY
    $events = $xpath->query('//result/event[text()="NEW"]');

    // Count number of events
    printf('There is %d events<br />', $events->length);

    // List all events
    for($i = 0; $i < ($events->length); $i++) {
        $event = $events->item($i);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, Have tried that one, result came as "There is 0 events" .. couldn't get it to work, but found a part solution myself. Isn't perfect so far, but not much is missing i think.

Comment: The XPath expression is slightly wrong, I think: it should be `event[type="NEW"]` not `event[text()="NEW"]`.

Answer (score 0):

> Would be someone able to tell me how i could specify now in that skript how to SKIP all OLD ?

You can introduce a condition right at the beginning of your foreach-loop that checks if the actual `$event` entry is to be skipped (filtered-out) and if so, skip to the next entry in loop:

```
foreach ($events->event as $event) {
    $skip = $event->type != 'NEW';
    if ($skip) {
        continue;
    }
    ...
```

Please see [`continue`](http://php.net/continue) (and its sister [`break`](http://php.net/break)) to control loop structures in PHP.